# Remove empty values from array--or equivalent

Tags: php, arrays

I have a bunch of variables I want to display of which some are empty. Some vars have spaces in them I want to preserve.  I would like to display them as a comma delimited list.  If I echo them sequentially `var1, var2,.var6,.var10,` I get extra commas where there are empties.  Doesn't sound like it would be that hard to delete the extra commas, but my ideas have not worked.

Since I have many, many of these, I don't want to have to condition printing every one--allowing for first or last in placement of commas  or iteratively replacing multiple commas with 1 comma or something complicated.. i.e. I'd like to find a simple repeatable approach that can be used whenever this comes up.

One idea was to convert the string into an array and delete empty values.  I can strip out empty spaces and echoing, can print `var1,var2,,,var8,,,` with no problem.  However, I can't find a way to delete the commas i.e., the empty values in array.

I tried:

```
$array = "one,two,,,six,,,ten";
$array= array_filter($array);
foreach($array as $val) {
echo $val;}}
foreach($array as $val) {
if ($val!=""&$val!=NULL) {
echo $val;}}
}
```

it doesn't get rid of commas.   Have not had luck with following suggestions on web:

```
array_flip(array_flip($array); or
$array = array_values($array); or
```

Could be typo on my end, but would appreciate any suggestions from the experienced.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you can not delete then is because you are not working with a valid array .. to work with a valid array you need to do this :

```
$array = "one,two,,,six,,,ten";
$array = explode(",",$array);
$array= array_filter($array);

var_dump($array);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'one' (length=3)
  1 => string 'two' (length=3)
  4 => string 'six' (length=3)
  7 => string 'ten' (length=3)
```

To convert back to string use `implode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
    var_dump(implode(",", $array))
```

Output

```
string 'one,two,six,ten' (length=15)
```

Thanks
:)

Comment: I left out a line $array = array("one,two,three"); which I was using instead of explode however, that must not have been doing the trick as using explode did allow the filter to work.  I was able to trim the array to the desired values.  Echoing, did not produce commas.  So I took your second suggestion and imploded and this did the job.  Thanks!  Out of curiosity as I am learning, what is the difference between explode and array("one","two", 'three")?

Comment: use use explode to turn a string to an array of elements